# Two computers both show as the same machine

Tags: macos, mac, clone, teamviewer

I have had team viewer installed on computer A for quite some time. I purchased Computer B and used Mac software to effectively make a clone of A on B. Now, however, I cannot get team viewer to recognize A and B as separate machines despite several uninstall / reinstall efforts as well as changing machine names. I have a few other computers that I can connect to / from without issue, but when both A and B are online, they show as the same machine and I can only connect to B from a third computer- attempting to connect to A from B or vice versa gives me a "you can't connect to your own device" error. I have changed nicknames and passwords on A and B, but those changes are reflected on the other machine as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's correct when you make a clone.
Close TeamViewer.
Open the Finder and go to this Path:

```
/Library/Preferences
```

and delete this file:

```
com.teamviewer.teamviewer9.plist
```

After them you can start the TeamViewer again.